# IO Exception: "java.io.FileNotFoundException: .\data (Access is denied) in h2 databse Restore

Tags: java, jpa, h2, filenotfoundexception

I want restore zip file of my h2 database backup, so i use `JFileChooser` to select `.zip` file and restore it with code below.

The `"./data"` is my database directory that i want restore files from my backup directory `("./backup")` to `"./data"`.

But getting following error:

> IO Exception: java.io.FileNotFoundException: .\data (Access is denied).

This is my code:

```
public void Restore() {
    emf.close();


    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser("./backup");
    FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter(
            "ZIP", "zip");
    chooser.setFileFilter(filter);
    int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
    if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {

        String fileName = chooser.getSelectedFile().getName();
        String directory = "./data";

        //DeleteDbFiles.execute("./data", "mydata", false);

        Restore.execute(directory, fileName, "mydata");
        System.out.println("restore completed");
    }
}
```

And this is error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" org.h2.message.DbException: IO Exception: "java.io.FileNotFoundException: .\data (Access is denied)"; "./data" [90031-199]
at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:194)
at org.h2.message.DbException.convertIOException(DbException.java:392)
at org.h2.tools.Restore.execute(Restore.java:194)
at MainForm.Restore(MainForm.java:791)
at MainForm$15.actionPerformed(MainForm.java:319)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2238)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2296)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4897)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4534)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4475)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2282)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:760)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:733)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:730)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLNonTransientException: IO Exception: "java.io.FileNotFoundException: .\data (Access is denied)"; "./data" [90031-199]
at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:502)
at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:427)
... 41 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: .\data (Access is denied)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93)
at org.h2.store.fs.FilePathDisk.newInputStream(FilePathDisk.java:337)
at org.h2.store.fs.FileUtils.newInputStream(FileUtils.java:224)
at org.h2.tools.Restore.getOriginalDbName(Restore.java:77)
at org.h2.tools.Restore.execute(Restore.java:148)
... 38 more
```

Comment: `Access Denied` means that the user who is trying to access the file doesn't have permissions to do it.

Comment: ok, what can we do?

Comment: You have to think about who (which OS user) is running the Java application and who is the owner of the file. `ls -a` to see permissions.

Comment: Looks to me as if you attempt to open a directory rather than a file, even though there is `fileName`. Exception says `"java.io.FileNotFoundException: .\data (Access is denied)"` and `.\data` is a folder as far as I am concerned.

Comment: i change directory to "./backup/name.zip". and error fixed, but it create a file (name.zip) in project directory.
i want restore files to "./data" directory. because it is my database directory.

Comment: Just for the tip : please see this link: http://www.h2database.com/javadoc/org/h2/tools/Restore.html.
the first parameter is zip file name and second is directory, but i use upside down because it did not work.